# Merging Windows Forms Application - Win32 Project Application

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, windowsformsintegration

Is there any way merging Windows Forms Application with Win32 Project Application (VS 2012), both written in Visual C++?

Windows Forms Application plays video (via vlc plugin) and Win32 Project Application displays the codes of a joypad (via a dialog box). I want an executable doing both. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MFC, you should read the following article:
[Integrate Windows Forms Into Your MFC Applications Through C++ Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163605.aspx)
And see here: [Windows Forms and Unmanaged Applications Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229600)

If you just want to show a dialog, this should not be a problem; if you want to embedd a control, you should use ActiveX controls.

See also: http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/MixingMFCAndWinForms.aspx

Comment: I don't use MFC in my Win32 Project. In the dialog box, I drag the vlc  plugin and I added in Properties, the location of the video. I noticed that resource.h file added itself #define IDC_OCX1, which refers to the vlc plugin. Build has no errors, but I can't run the .exe. What I am missing?